# SQL Server 2008 Split 1 column into 3 (Shipping dimensions)

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I have a table with with one column for product dimensions.

example rows:

`16" L x 22" W x 6" H
22.5" L x 12" W x 9" H`

I am trying to get the length, width, and height into separate columns.  I have to use SQL because this is being used in a software integration that only accepts SQL statements.  I am thinking I have to go the route of regex.

SQL Statement to get the data so far
`SELECT TOP 10 
      [ID]
     ,substring([SHIP_DIMENSIONS],PATINDEX('%[0-9]\"%',[SHIP_DIMENSIONS]),2) as Length
     ,substring([SHIP_DIMENSIONS],PATINDEX('%[0-9]\"%',[SHIP_DIMENSIONS]),2) as Width
     ,substring([SHIP_DIMENSIONS],PATINDEX('%[0-9]*\"%',[SHIP_DIMENSIONS]),2) as Height
FROM [PART]`

I need the output to be 

`Length | Width | Height
  16   |  22   |   6 
  22.5 |  12   |   9`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have free reign over the database design / table structure I would strongly recommend starting by improving the data model.  Ideally you should have at least separate columns for the different types of data you store.  It ties in with what you are trying to achieve (and common sense too!)

Comment: I dont have access to change the table design :(.  I agree that these should be separated to begin with.

Comment: Also what does `TOP` mean without `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Its grabbing only 10 results so I dont have to deal with all the other 100,000 or records.  Made it easier to look at

Comment: Working with strings as you are, I think regex is a sensible way to go.  You may wish to ensure the length section contains an L after it, and so on.

Comment: No, you don't need RegEx for this. You can clean this up further of course, [but here's a start](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/315b0/1).

Comment: Well, we don't have your other 100,000 rows, so the TOP is pretty meaningless to us.

Comment: Do the columns always have the structure `<number>" L x <number>" W x <number>" H`, or can the space before the L, W, or H be missing? Can the order of L, W, and H change? Can one or more of L, W, H be missing?

Comment: The structure should be the same.  As you mentioned '<number>" L x <number>" W x <number>" H'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
select
    left(dim, charindex('" L', dim)-1) as [Length]
,   substring(dim, charindex('" L', dim)+6, charindex('" W', dim)-charindex('" L x ', dim) - 6) as [Width]
,   substring(dim, charindex('" W', dim)+6, charindex('" H', dim)-charindex('" W x ', dim) - 6) as [Height]
from test
```

The idea is to look for the markers that you have in your text, and use them to parcel out the string into substrings. This approach is very rigid, in that it assumes that the pattern shown in your example is followed precisely in all your records, i.e. all the markers are present, along with the spaces. There is also an implicit assumption that all dimensions are in inches. What can vary is the width of the columns.

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4334d/1)

Note: I am assuming that you are dealing with a legacy database, so there is no way to do the right thing (which is to separate out the dimensions into separate columns).

Comment: Just seems a bit Neanderthal compared to regex which is so cool! :)

Comment: @ne1410s Not all RDBMS engines have support for "cool" regular expressions. SQL Server 2008's regex capabilities are rather limited (I'm being extremely polite there).

Comment: Nice!  I this is exactly what I was looking for.  Now, I see that I must have an anomaly with the data because I am getting an error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function".  Now to find that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's a good point. I was wondering also about the relative cost of regex vs substring on different server versions / or indeed in general.  (thinking of those 100,000 records). +1 for controlling yourself =D

Comment: @ne1410s It's not just about performance, there can be significant roadblocks to turning CLR on, regardless of how much easier it may make certain queries.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - I'm intrigued. I suppose some bright sparks have been hard at work optimising such things in this years' SQL offering?.. Making queries easier should be their goal, right?  Can things be improved with configuring your datatable appropriately, e.g. indexing?

Comment: @ne1410s Wha? I'm saying that CLR is not enabled by default, so you can't just "turn RegEx on" - even in SQL Server 2014. And the things that prevent it from being turned on are usually political and centered around risks involving security, required testing, etc. And no, no index alone can fix the performance implications of splitting up the data as presented in this question. The only real hope - since fixing the design has alreadsy been ruled out - is having other sargable expressions to narrow down the number of rows this string parsing will have to operate on.

Comment: New SO question: "should politics prevent progress?"   [Answer: no - but it does and always will. Get over it]

Comment: @ne1410s That is not an on-topic question for SO in any shape or form. Try [workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com), [quora](https://www.quora.com/), or [Yahoo answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/). I'm not sure exactly what "it" is that *I* need to "get over"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61004/discussion-between-ne1410s-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: @ne1410s Nor do I have any intention whatsoever of having a prolonged discussion about this with you, sorry. Plain and simple fact, and I'm leaving it at this: ***RegEx in SQL Server is NOT POSSIBLE FOR EVERYONE***.

Comment: And I'm leaving it at: IT WAS HYPOTHETICAL!  It is *I* who has to do the getting-over!